# _api/web/lists/ vs. listdata.svc - or: hot to get Likes or Ratings?

Tags: rest, listdata.svc

Working with SharePoint 2013 onPremise here. And it is driving me nuts :-(

i have a custom list with attachments and Likes enabled. And I want to retrieve both via REST - which seems impossible if I also want to $select only a certain set of fields

First, the listdata.svc: Its great, I can select sub-properties of linked lists, I can expand and select Attachments and filter on all of this, like

```
?$expand=ContactTags,StoryTags,TopicTags,Attachments&$select=Id,Title,Overview,PoV,Overview_CP,Overview_EN,Overview_FI,Overview_HC,Overview_IG,Overview_INS,Overview_PI,Overview_PS,Overview_TMT,ContactTags/Id,StoryTags/Id,TopicTags/Id,Attachments,Modified&$filter=
```

BUT adding LikesCount (or simply trying LikesCount alone for simplicity):

```
_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Topic_DB?$select=LikesCount
```

results in

```
Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.Topic_DBItem' does not have a property named 'LikesCount'."
```

Its already apparent when not specifying any query options at all, no social fields are returned by the listdata.svc

On the other hand, looking at _web/api/

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Topic_DB')/Items/?$select=LikesCount
```

does return the expected field! But as mentioned, I want more. Attachments for example:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Topic_DB')/Items/?$expand=AttachmentFiles&$select=AttachmentFiles
```

but guess what?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "-2147024809, System.ArgumentException",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "Value does not fall within the expected range."
    }
  }
}
```

The only way to get Attachment details AND LikesCount seems to be to go with _web/api/lists and no $select at all? Huge waste of bandwidth with all the unneeded data and metadata returned.

Any hints on listdata.svc and social content?

Comment: maybe try using "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Topic_DB" without filter to check whether LikesCount field is in the returning data schema.
I noticed sometime the field name are different in these two approaches.

Comment: unfortunately it does nto show up in the unfiltered response, so its apparently not available in the listdata.svc :-(

Comment: I always thought there was a simpler side-by-side comparison for _vti_bin/ListData.svc and _api/web